# Apache HTTPS Server has stopped working XAMPP

Tags: php, apache, xampp

```
Problem Event Name:    APPCRASH
  Application Name: httpd.exe
  Application Version:  2.4.18.0
  Application Timestamp:    5667f02e
  Fault Module Name:    StackHash_a2ad
  Fault Module Version: 6.3.9600.18821
  Fault Module Timestamp:   59ba8666
  Exception Code:   c0000374
  Exception Offset: PCH_22_FROM_ntdll+0x0003C8AC
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: a2ad
  Additional Information 2: a2ad1e9ca9dbf2621b83327a68a5efd6
  Additional Information 3: 083c
  Additional Information 4: 083cecac304c4493a6ebba6a971d218c
```

I have checked for an online solution but none worked. Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: have you tried switching it on and off ?

Comment: Restarting does not help?

Comment: No. Restart isn't helping.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem:

> 1 - stop apache web server from xampp panel
>
> 2 - choose (httpd.conf) from config menu on xampp panel
>
> 3 -insert code to the end of file

```
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
  ThreadStackSize 8388608
</IfModule>
```